# Amount of acceptable Memory Leak

Tags: xcode, ipad, memory-leaks, unity-game-engine

How much memory leak is negligible?

In my program, I am using `Unity` and when I go through `Profile` > `Leaks` and work with the project it shows about total 16KB memory Leak caused by `Unity` and I cannot help that.

EDIT: After a long play with the program it amounts to a 400KB leak.

What should I do? Is this amount of memory leak acceptable for an iPad project?

Comment: Is that a *rate* of leakage? I mean, if you ran the app 10 times as long (interacting with it) would the leak be 160K?

Comment: I has set to Kill project after exit, so every time I start new session and running 10 times is same as running 1 time.

Comment: Some thoughts, in no particular order: You say "After a long play", define "long".  Have you done an independent evaluation, IE, running your code on the device in question and watching its memory usage outside of Unity.  Do you see a leak if you build an empty unity project?  Do you use 3rd party libraries linked to Unity?  Are you sure this is a leak and not a part of the engine Unity is hiding.  For instance when you tested the game over a "long" period of time, did you leave the controls alone to make sure you weren't triggering anything in game that might spawn objects.

Comment: Part2:  I'm not sure of Mono's internals but if their garbage collection is mark and sweep, you can't really assume a memory leak just because the program isn't releasing old memory right away.  I don't believe mono is reference counted.

Comment: @Jerdak , part1: for my program long means working for 20 min because my project is like a kind of calculator that user need to work with it less than 3 min and got his answer. as i tried an Unity project with one object also make some leaks that is their bug, yes I have 3rd party libraries,

Comment: part2: when i go through the solving the leak problem (I cover most of them) but some of them become zombie, when I solve that again it shows me memory leak. @last I could not go further, is this much acceptable or memory leak should be 0?

Comment: @nfarshchi I hesitate to call any leak "acceptable". I'd say run the app for an hour, if you don't see more than several hundred KBs worth of what you think might be a "leak" then its "acceptable". If this really is a problem with Unity, I doubt the iOS approval process is rejecting such apps or we'd have a lot less Unity based apps in the stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not great, but it won't get your app rejected unless it causes a crash in front of a reviewer. The size is less important than how often it occurs. If it only occurs once every time the app is run, that's not a big deal. If it happens every time the user does something, then that's more of a problem.

It's probably a good idea for you to track down these bugs and fix them, because Objective C memory management is quite different compared to Java, and it's good to get some practice in with smaller stuff before you're stuck trying to debug a huge problem with a deadline looming.

Comment: The problem is the leaks are out of my hand, they are related to `Unity` object that I have in my project and I can not help it. 16K that I said is the main leak ,after playing with program for long long time it shows me 400KB leak.

Comment: if its crashing the app after some amount of time then there will be problem otherwise there will be no problem in terms of accepting the app on AppStore.

Comment: it will not crash, my question is for accepting in AppStore is there any limit for memory leak? what about in real, does the user feel this? does is affect the performance?

Comment: there is no hard limit defined to that, it might affect the performance.

Comment: you said it might affect the performance, so that is my exact question. if it be 400K will it affect the performance or 400K is nothing in 512MB of ram? as I mention in the title of topic how much memory leak is acceptable?

Comment: Every app gets a distinct amount of memory to run within the app sandbox. It certainly does not amount to 512MB, but rather something around 50 - 100MB / app, probably depending on the processes running in the background. The amount is assigned by the OS and you can never be sure how much it will be for your app at a random point in time.

Answer (score 1):

First, look if you can use Unity in another way to circumvent the leak (if you have enough insight into the workings of this framework).
Then, report the leakage to the Unity developers if not already done (by you or someone else).
Third, if you absolutely rely on this framework, hope it get fixed ASAP, unless switching to another framework is an option for you.
A 400K leak is not a very big deal unless it amounts to that size within few minutes. **Though, no matter how small the leak, it is always necessary to keep an eye on any leak caused by your or third party code and try to get rid of them in the next minor or major iteration of your app.**